# How to use locale structure for I18n.localize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, locale, yaml, rails-i18n

The provided locale structure in the [I18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) can look like the [following](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/de.yml):

```
de:
  date:
    abbr_day_names:
    - So
    - Mo
    - Di
    - Mi
    - Do
    - Fr
    - Sa
```

But trying to output the day as [described in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) doesn't work, it seems like it looks for a `format:` in the locale aswell?

```
I18n.locale = :de
l(Date.current, format: :abbr_day_names)
```

"I18n::MissingTranslationData: translation missing: de.date.formats.abbr_day_names"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you should do (french used):

```
  date:
    abbr_day_names: [Dim, Lun, Mar, Mer, Jeu, Ven, Sam]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Jan, Fév, Mar, Avr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Août, Sep, Oct, Nov, Déc]
    day_names: [Dimanche, Lundi, Mardi, Mercredi, Jeudi, Vendredi, Samedi]
    formats:
      day_month: "%b %d"
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      hour: "%H:%M"
      long: "%A %d %B %Y"
      long_month: "%d %B %Y"
      month_abbr: "%d %b %Y"
```

So in `date.abbr_day_names` you define the abbreviated day names, same for `date.abbr_months_names`. Then you can set a custom format located in `date.formats.name_of_your_format`

---

**In your view**, you would use it this way:

```
l(Date.current, format: :long)
# OR
l(Date.current, format: :month_abbr)
# etc.
```

It works the same with `datetime.formats` and `time.formats`.

---

Here is an example of a common `en-US.yml` file for date/time formats: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-US.yml

I can't find the full documentation about every wildcards usable in the i18n localization system. If somebody knows where to get it, your input will be greatly appreciated!